# Android: system call getView twice when activity created

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom list with about 20 item and three lines each item. 
I used a Log to trace how getView method is called

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.e("getView", "at position " + position);
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
    }
            // my code here

}
```

Then, when list item loaded, i received this log

"getView", "at position 0"; 
"getView", "at position 1"; 
"getView", "at position 2"; 
"getView", "at position 3"; 
"getView", "at position 0"; 
"getView", "at position 1"; 
"getView", "at position 2"; 
"getView", "at position 3"; 
"getView", "at position 4"; 
"getView", "at position 5"; 
..............

Can anyone tell me why getView method called twice from 0 to 3 ?

Comment: I don't know but it's the same for me, I just tested. I would like to know, too.

Comment: please post your custom adapter code,to tell the exact solution

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me why getView method called twice from 0 to 3?

The `getView` method is called twice because the `ListView` , as part of it's `onMeasure` method, calls the `getView`  method of the adapter to get the row's `View` to see how big they are. I guess you have three visible rows, so the `ListView` will call the `getView` method three times for this first three visible children.

Comment: Exactly, all items in fisrt screen call getView twice. Here is logs: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?x98x5fpbywcmt0q#

Comment: @MrStone There is no need to post the logs again, I've told you why. You could test this by looking at the source code for the `ListView` or by using a simple overrided `ListView` to see that the three first calls are happening from the `onMeasure` method. Use this `ListView`( https://gist.github.com/3196065 ) instead of the normal one and check the logs